# How to show "Not all items showing" VBA Autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large dataset in excel with 70000 record and each reccord different from other.
When I'm try to use autofilter in VBA, they take a lot of time to filter (in this case is filter color)

But when I do it on another computer with excel 365, it show "Not all item showing", and it's performing better. Are there anyway I can change the setting or using to VBA to see "Not all items showing" everytime so that it give better performance.

[image]

Comment: Upgrade to 365. VBA can't change what's available in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Advance Filter using VBA.
Basically what I do, I always use advance filter and put the result in separate sheet. I get the output very quickly and since it is filtered data, it would be easy to do further operations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).